# building model with Einstein requires at least two intents with twenty utterances before they can be sent to be built

Tags: salesforce-einstein

I'm trying to build an Einstein chat bot with dialogue intent. I'm following the steps mentioned 
[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_natural_language_processing.htm)

I have added two intent with 21 utterances in each intent. But still I'm getting the same issue. Kindly refer the screen shot

[image]

[image]

Help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create intents for at least two dialogs.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Given that the error message @Sonia is receiving states as much, they'll likely require more direction on what is required here. Can you edit your answer to provide more specific guidance?

Comment: user12975286 can you please elaborate your answer? I already have created two intents,Appointment status & order status. Screen shot is given in my question

Answer (score 1):

My error message disappear. Initially I have created two intents but linked one intent with dialogue after adding 2nd intent with another dialogue the error message disappeared